# How to create, edit global variables (phone number) in django CMS?

Tags: django, content-management-system, global-variables, django-cms

I want to add a telephone number which will be printed in the header and the footer on every page. I want to set the value of the number once and place instances. I call that a global variable.
I thought static placeholders would do that but I don't get the concept of how django-cms handles this thing.

Is it possible to create and edit global variables which can be edited in the administration backend?

Comment: Had a conflict with my custom Cascading Stylesheet selectors and the django-cms toolbar css selectors. Question can be closed. I'm sorry for any inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that is not a Django-CMS problem. The question may be how could i store and edit my "Global Variables" in django?

```
class Global_variables(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

could be your answer.